# NSLog, comments and releasing app

Tags: ios, app-store

Do I need to delete all NSLog commands and every comment lines ( /*  [...]  */ )before releasing my application and putting it on Appstore?

Comment: You should read a good book on C. You seem to be lacking fundamental knowledge about the language and its nature. Comments are gone during the compilation phase - if you don't understand this, you should not be writing iOS apps yet, instead, you should be learning the basics of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NSLog**: They *should* be removed.  As pointed out by @sosborn, NSLog is slow and can cause and even hide subtle timing and concurrency bugs.  For basic debugging NSLog is fantastic, but after you're done debugging you really should remove them.  @Elf Sundae's answer is fantastic and shows you how to make it so NSLogs will be displayed **ONLY** when debugging and automagically hid when you release your application.

**Comments**: No

Comment: NSLog can be slow and it can cause/hide subtle timing/concurrency bigs.

Comment: Yes, absolutely!  I can't tell you how many times I've had that happen to me.  But for a simple application (which is what I assume op has made) it doesn't matter.

Comment: It's a big assumption that the OP made a "simple" app. Also, people other than OP will be using these answers.

Comment: Very true.  Editing my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You can open `NSLog` only in DEBUG building.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
        #define NSLog(fmt, ...)     NSLog((@"%@ [Line: %d] %s " fmt),[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
        #define NSLog(fmt, ...)
#endif
```

put it to the global header file or `Prefix.pch`

Comment: it is a precompiled header